How to handle spaces in filepath of ghostscript commands
I'm trying to run a ghostscript(10.01.2) command to convert a pdf to pdf/a through a Python subprocess call on Windows 10:
subprocess.call(f(gs -dPDFA=2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndepedentColor -SDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=2 - {gsOutput} {gsInput})

I'm finding that ghostscript can't handle filepaths with spaces in them such as \Documents\My PDFs\file1.pdf and instead read it as additional arguments, returning the error:
Error: /undefinedfilename in (PDFs\\file.pdf)
Ghostscript also doesn't seem to be able to solve with simply with "" quotations around the filepath.
Is there a simple way to deal with spaces in filepaths for ghostscript commands? Unfortunately simply avoiding spaces in the path is not a solution in my case.
Some attempted solutions:
gsInput = f"{str(Path(/Documents/My PDFs/file1.pdf))}"
gsInput = str(Path(/Documents/My PDFs/file1.pdf).replace(' ','%20')

Not sure what other methods to try at this point.

Ghostscript also doesn't seem to be able to solve with simply with "" quotations around the filepath This absolutely should work.  Please show the code you tried.

The obvious first thing to do is try it from the command line. Does that work ? If so then the problem is obviously the format of your subprocess.call. The paths you state in the tiny code snippet and the error message do not correspond which does not inspire confidence.

It 'looks like' (and I'm totally guessing here because you haven't given any code for this) you have set 'gsOutput' to also be a path containing a space, and you have not put quotes around that path. Assuming that gsOutput is something like '-sOutputFile=/Documents/My PDFs/file.pdf'. This leads to Ghostscript parsing -sOutputFile as '/Documents/My' then reading the space as an argument separator, then reading 'PDFs/file.pdf' as the first input file. So you get an undefinedfilename error on 'PDFs/file.pdf' instead of 'PDFs/file1'.pdf' which is why the error and code don't match!

Ghostscript has no problems running as a Windows console shell command
However windows OS allows for LFNs with spaces which are alien to Posix or other OS systems that Ghostscript and Python expect as common ground.
For that reason in Windows when debugging console functions , it is best to use a batch.cmd file with error feedback. Here we can drop a PDF onto that Windows GUI console, to show errors before making changes to suit the OS SHELL commands.

Thus we can see which PDFs would fail with such a command line, here the Alpha kitten PDF is not suited to that combination.
If the syntax is correct we can expect to see no error message and can test the file for PDF/A-2b compatibility

So now we can drag and drop or "SendTo" or PYTHON OSSHELL pdf2pdfa2b "file name"
pdf2pdfA2b.cmd
rem supplied GSset files fail to fully account for Windows C:\Program Files\ syntax so set env variables to suit here but may fail later so be aware! edit to suite your own files and locations
set "GS=C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.03.0\bin\gswin32.exe"
set "GSC=C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.03.0 \bin\gswin32c.exe"
set "in=%~dpn1.pdf"
REM for PDF/A-2b you will need the CUSTOMISED definition file to be in working directory
set "def=%~dp0PDFA_def.ps"
set "out=%~dpn1-pdfA-2b.pdf"

"%GS%" -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  -dPDFA=2 -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=2 -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor  -o"%out%" --permit-file-read="%def%" -f "%in%"
pause

NOTE GS will not complain if the "def" file is missing or incorrect.
HOWEVER with or without it there is still a risk you will get

Thus you need to test all files of a particular type, for just like the kitten are they suited to PDF/A-2B conversion in that way!
